# "MSCAL.OCX" error when moving from Access 2007 to 2010: I don't have a calendar

Tags: upgrade, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have a database created in Access 2007. When opening it in Access 2010 I get the following error:

> "Your Microsoft Office Access database or project contains a missing
>   or broken reference to the file MSCAL.OCX version 7.0."

Searching for this error, I found out that it is caused by the removal of the calendar control. The use of 'datapicker' is recommended instead. The problem is that AFAIK my database does not use the calendar control! I have been using the datepicker throughout.

1. Is there any other type of object/control in that file the removal of which could be causing my problem?
2. Is there a way to scan through the database to find out where I might be referring to that file? It is possible that a calendar control was added to a form at some point, and then deleted. Could that have left traces somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check any/all Forms and ensure there is no calendar object on them; I don't know of an automated way to find all instances of an object in Access forms.

To kill the reference try this:

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA code window, and then go to `Tools->References`.

Un-check the references to the MS Calendar (MSCAL.OCX; probably has "MISSING" next to it), OK and save the DB.

Comment: Thanks! Unchecking the box next to MS Calendar in the References window of VBA did the trick.